# Django and Celery logs

Tags: python, django, celery

We have a Django app (with Celery) that process several tens of thousands of http requests per minute.
We are getting a huge volume of logs from Django like

```
ip... - - [date...] "POST /url... HTTP/1.0" 200 311 "-" "libcurl-agent/1.0"
```

and logs from Celery like

```
INFO:celery.worker.strategy:Task backend.tasks.my_task_name[62c288f0-63ad-45b5-8abd-bbfe11a8b612] received
INFO:celery.app.trace:Task backend.tasks.my_task_name[c633ad89-9e2c-4622-bf50-077d8dcf61b6] succeeded in 0.008994809817522764s: None
```

How can I limit these logs?
From one side I want to know that the app works. On another side, it is too much log data.
Can I set something like store no more 5 log lines per second exclude errors?

Answer (score -3):

Sounds like you need to check how the Celery is setup in your project. I don't know your source code, but here is a good article on [some good practices with django and celery](https://discuss.dizzycoding.com/django-celery-logging-best-practice/)

Comment: That site is just blatantly re-hosting content from StackOverflow.